# Android activity starts automatically -- not desired

Tags: android

New to Android development, couldn't find help via google, please forgive me if someone is able to find my answer.

[I'm working on this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage) and I got through to the end of it, working through tiny kinks since it appears the tutorial isn't up to date with their IDE. There's supposed to be a simple text box where you can type something in and hit the send button and then it starts a new activity consisting of a new text view and just displays that message.

When I compile and run the application in the emulator, it appears that it just automatically launches the second activity automatically and displays a default "Hello World!" string instead of bringing up my text box and send button to get started. Before I tried to include the second activity and use the intent feature, the textbox and button were there, so I think it's somehow just auto-starting the new activity before I get a chance to make any input. Could someone tell me why that is?

I got to the point where I copy/pasted their code to make sure I didn't have any typos or anything. my activity_main.xml file does indeed specify "onClick" before attempting to start the method that invokes the new activity, so I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong elsewhere or this is just due to a discrepancy in the tutorial.

On a related note, if their tutorial is a less than ideal way for me to begin learning to develop for android I would love suggestions or a point in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Here's my manifest code:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the MainActivity.java file:
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

Here's the DisplayMessageActivity.java file:
    package com.example.myfirstapp;

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    // Create the text view
    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(message);

    // Set the text view as the activity layout
    setContentView(textView);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_message, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: From where are you calling the sendMessage() method?

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't find any issue based on your description and your code. Could you create a new project and redo the tutorial? Also, close all unrelated projects (should be all except `support-v7`) before you run the new one.

Comment: I'll have to do it tomorrow, I've run out of time to work on it tonight. Job & Family leave only so much time for me to do this. But that is encouraging, I'll redo it tomorrow and get back to you. Thank you!

Comment: Can we see activity_display_message.xml ? Does it have just the `Hello World!` text in it?

Answer (score 0):

In manifest check if your second activity has intent filter like this inside your second activity tag. This makes the second activity, your starting activity. remove this code and put this code inside the first activity tag alone.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I think my manifest is accurate if I'm understanding you correctly. I edited the original post to include my manifest file.

Comment: can you post the MainActivity class? I think you called startActivity to second activity in onCreate or onResume...

Comment: SendMessage is called from xml event? Give us the layout

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project and started over, and worked the second time. I compared the new project's code against what I had posted here and noticed this line under the onCreate method of the MainActivity class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
```

In the working version, it was set to:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

No idea how it got changed, but it's obviously starting the other activity before I was able to do anything. Thanks for the help!